# How to hash ftp password in table but send it unhashed in request

Tags: php, hash, ftp

I am wanting to store the ftp connection password in the db so that members do not have to always type the information in when they update the plugin.  However cPanel does not use hash on the ftp passwords. They must be sent clean.  I just ran a test using password_hash() and the connection failed.

If i am seeing this right it means i have only a few choices.

A. use a two way encryption instead of a one way hash and decrypt it before it is sent.

B. dont use a hash at all and just use some kind of encoding like base64 that can easily be undone to send it.

Right now it is being stored in session which to me is not secure either but i don't control that end of it.

Do i have any other choices here ?

Thanks

Comment: There's no such thing as a 2-way hash.

Comment: `base64` isn't encryption, it's just a simple encoding.

Comment: You might as well store it in plain text, because whatever method you use to extract the password to send it to cPanel could also be done by anyone who has access to the DB.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use FTP, and not a more secure protocol like SCP, that uses public key authentication?

Comment: Thanks, so that means i am pretty much stuck with storing it in a non secure way.

Comment: yeah im stuck with ftp because many users dont have SCP set up and that would be a whole other battle.

Comment: ok so the proper term is two way encryption right, sorry for my misuse of the term i have corrected the other one in the orginal post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, you must protect database from  intrusions, the ftp password you can store in plain text without encoding or encryption. if you want to be secure, use secure protocol as SCP or SFTP.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i do plan to let the users know that they need to setup the ftp or sftp in a way that does not allow any more access than needed so if it is sub domain then that is all it can access, that way if something does go wrong they cant get into the other domains or the root.